Flutter with OneSignal PushNotification doesn't trigger addForegroundWillDisplayListener when the app is closed or enters background
I have this code
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:wv_app_temp/Constants.dart';
import 'package:wv_app_temp/functionalities/NotificationStorage.dart';
import 'package:wv_app_temp/main.dart';

List<OldNotification> readNotificationsFromSharedp(
    SharedPreferences sp, String dataKey) {
  List<OldNotification> nots = List.empty(growable: true);
  List<String>? favList = sp.getStringList(dataKey);
  if (favList != null) {
    nots = favList
        .map((fav) => OldNotification.fromJson(json.decode(fav)))
        .toList();
  }
  return nots;
}

bool isElementNotExistByURL(List<OldNotification> list, OldNotification obj) {
  for (final e in list) {
    if (e.url == obj.url) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
  AppConstants constants = new AppConstants();
  OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose);
  OneSignal.Debug.setAlertLevel(OSLogLevel.none);
  OneSignal.initialize(constants.OneSignalKey);
  OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);
  OneSignal.Notifications.addClickListener((event) {
    print('NOTIFICATION CLICK LISTENER CALLED WITH EVENT: $event');
    String url = event.notification.additionalData!['myappurl'];

    webController!.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri(url)));
  });

  OneSignal.Notifications.addForegroundWillDisplayListener((event) async {
    print(
        'NOTIFICATION WILL DISPLAY LISTENER CALLED WITH: ${event.notification.jsonRepresentation()}');

    /// Display Notification, preventDefault to not display
    event.preventDefault();
    event.notification.display();

    String title = event.notification.title!;
    String url = event.notification.additionalData!['myappurl'];
    String someBody = event.notification.body!.length > 10
        ? event.notification.body!.substring(0, 10)
        : event.notification.body!;

    //initialize file
    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    //reading old notificationd from file
    List<OldNotification> oldDatas =
        readNotificationsFromSharedp(sp, 'SavedNotifications');

    OldNotification newSingleData = OldNotification(
        title: title, url: url, body: someBody, isOpened: false);
    if (isElementNotExistByURL(oldDatas, newSingleData)) {
      oldDatas.add(newSingleData);

      //writing to file
      var correctedOrder = oldDatas.reversed.toList();
      List<String> favListing =
          correctedOrder.map((fav) => jsonEncode(fav.toJson())).toList();
      sp.setStringList('SavedNotifications', favListing);
    } else {
      print('Already saved notification.');
    }
  });
}

What I want to achieve is that when a notification arrives, it will be saved to shared preference and then I will list them later in the notification UI. This and other features work well, if the app is opened. But if the app is closed and a notification arrives, it doesn't get saved in the shared preferences or trigger addForegroundWillDisplayListener. I'm using onesignal_flutter: ^5.2.2 and flutter 3.22.2
How to achieve this? Please help
I tried adding OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true); by assuming may be it's a permission problem.

'addForegroundWillDisplayListener' only works when the app is in the foreground.

Did you check this doc: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-notifications and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/pushing-background-updates-to-your-app?language=objc?
